# Append(ajax -data) outside screen (left:100%;)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to create a slider of posts. I charge the data using ajax and then I apply append to inject the content to a div (id=ajaxinserted1). But I don't want to add this data into screen. I want that data to be added outside of screen (left:100%), so then I can apply a CSS transition to get it on screen with a slide animation effect.

How could I append(data) into the DOM outside the screen?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code should dynamically calculate the offset based on the width of the images returned from the request. The explanation is in-line. This also required the container to be positioned absolutely.

```js
// Cache the element
var $container = $('.ajaxinserted1');

// Append the images to the container
$container.append(
 '<img src="https://www.placehold.it/100">',
 '<img src="https://www.placehold.it/100">',
 '<img src="https://www.placehold.it/100">',
 '<img src="https://www.placehold.it/100">'
)

// Store the offset value
var offsetLeft = 0;

// Loop over the images and update the offset value
$.each($container.children(), function(a, b) {
 offsetLeft = offsetLeft - b.width;
})

// Set the offset for the container
$container.css('left', offsetLeft);

// Animation
$('.ajaxinserted1').animate({
 left: "10px"
}, 500);
```

```css
.ajaxinserted1 {
 position: absolute;
}

.ajaxinserted1 img {
 padding: 10px;
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ajaxinserted1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks this idea works. I just do this. $container.css('left', '-150%'); and then animate(left:50%); and it works great. I have some issues when I test this on my iphone. It apply the $container.css('left', '-150%'), but dissplay the content for a few miliseconds

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just want to append your post under the existing ones and style it so it appears off screen so it can then slide in.  So maybe something like...

1) Append your new post HTML into the content div with a class on it called 'new-post'

2) With CSS for new-post class...

```
.new-post {
  position:relative;
  left:100%;
}
```

3) Do your CSS transition to slide it back on screen and remove the class once finished.

**Notes:**

- You may need to set the `left` attribute in absolute pixels, e.g. `600px`, it depends on the layout of your page and where you want it to slide in from.
- You could consider using `opacity:0` and doing a fade in transition as well